# HTML Form send an array of objects using thymeleaf and spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, forms, thymeleaf, alpine.js

I am trying to built an application where I need to send a list of objects, having a variable length.
[Form view]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ynE2T.png)

Is there any way I can capture such fields in the controller? I was trying something in the lines of:

```
public String setNewTratament(
        @RequestParam("medicamente") MedicamentatieStartStop[] input,
        Model model) {
      // ...
}
```

and in the post request something like:

```
<input x-bind:name="`medicamente[${index}][medicament]\`" type="text" class="input input-bordered w-full"\>
```

(using alpineJS), where the last field will be the properties of the object "MedicamentatieStartStop". The names are copied from an `th:inline` script, pasting exactly one such array.

The problem was it throws the following error: 'required request parameter 'medicamente' for method parameter type MedicamentatieStartStop[] is not present.

Any ideas how I should approach this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding a th:object on the form with a DTO and instead of [attribute] i changed it to .attribute, everything else stayed the same.